# Why does Pantone color bridge tell me one thing, but illustrator another?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pantone

Why is it that when I change the color from spot to process via my swatch options dialog box, it is different than the Color Bridge value in my swatch book? Take PMS 200 C, for example. When I change it from spot to proecess via the dropdown I get the build: 16.5,100,86.51,6.86-- but my color bridge book is reporting 3, 100, 70, 12?

Comment: Which one of the following is more accurate? In case one you ask for the directions to the train station and you get the same answer in all cities you could be in. Or case two you ask they ask for city and give instructions for that city. Guess which one is more likely to get you to the right location. Ok, but what if you give the wrong city? So adobes conversion has the potential to be more correct, but only of you feed the right info.

Answer (score 7):

With your Adobe CC programs comes a set of *color books* files. They are lookup tables with measured absolute [Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) colors for each ink.

When converting a Pantone swatch to CMYK in Illustrator, the Lab color of the ink is looked up in the color book and then converted to the set of CMYK values that comes closest to reproducing the Pantone ink.

This process uses the *Working CMYK Profile* of your document. Different color profiles will produce different sets of CMYK values.

The CMYK values provided in the Pantone Color Bridge are made using one specific (to me) unknown color profile. Using these values for different printing machines printing on different kinds of paper according to different standards *will* give different results. So I'm not really sure how helpful it is.

I would personally avoid using Pantone's "magic numbers" and rather rely on the conversion. And of course use my common sense and sometimes tweak the CMYK numbers if I believe it will give a color closer to what I want.

To illustrate my point, I have made this comparison (in InDesign):

[image]

The document has the color profile *Coated FOGRA39* so all CMYK colors are shown as they would look if printed according to that standard.

In the top we have how InDesign displays Pantone 200 C using the Lab color stored in the color book. Below we have that ink converted to four different color profiles and the values you find in Pantone's Color Bridge.

All different values and all different resulting colors.

(The CMYK numbers are rounded and you can always discuss exactly how to preview this, but it surely shows how color profile matters.)

Comment: If what you say is true and they are Lab derived I am just fine with that... I just can't believe how off these magic numbers Adobe is giving us are. So they are going to be wrong and they are going to sell whole books of them for years on end? This seems insane to me.

Comment: I share your amazement, but logically I can't see how Pantone should be able to find *one* set of CMYK values for each ink when we have to different use color profiles to convert images from RGB to CMYK for different purposes. Where does this magic come from? We've had a few similar questions: [1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/68390), [2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/80480), [3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/144740) and [more](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=pantone+bridge+cmyk).

Comment: @WG.Print.Beer.Designer, I've added an example to illustrate my point.

Comment: (Btw: You must mean *"how off these magic numbers **Pantone** is giving us are"*.)

Comment: Yes, that is true I meant Pantone when I said Adobe in my previous message. Seemingly the best way to go is match the color to the pantone while viewing it as the color profile your press will be printing in.

Comment: Yes and preferably comparing a calibrated screen to a printed sample. But then again they can vary a bit so it's all a bit fluid. A CMYK color will always look different than a solid ink. Life as a designer is easier if you avoid trying to match Pantone inks in CMYK.

Comment: Correct, it's matching the spot on the can to the blend on the box that is the challenge right now... Regarding folks working in the craft beer world I would recommend nailing down how that color is reproducing on aluminum and supplying your printing press whom is doing cartons with the decorated aluminum sample. The press will still do that sort of color matching work, at least so I believe.

Comment: I guess the ideal workflow (although costly) will involve sticking to the same subcontractors and through some tests find the best match. Even perhaps go backwards and change the Pantone ink on the bottle until you find something which is possible to recreate on the carton. *Or* design around it by deliberately using different colors for the two parts. Nothing wrong with having brown leather seats in a car with a red paint job.

Comment: If the press should color match for you they would have to either change the CMYK values in your PDF before print or change how much of each ink they apply and remember this setting to the next time they print for you. It's a bit much to ask perhaps. What if you don't think the match is good enough and they admit they changed your values? (I do prepress for an offset press )